# The partial view 'AllCars' was not found. The following locations were searched: /Views/Cars/AllCars.cshtml /Views/Shared/AllCars.cshtml

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a problem when starting a project with the given code

```
<h1>All cars</h1>
<h3>@Model.currCategory</h3>
<div class="row mt-5 mb-2">
    @{
        foreach (Car car in Model.allCars)
        {
            @Html.Partial("AllCars",car)
        }
    }
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUysa.png)

who knows what can help?
add controller code

```
using Shop.Data.Models;

namespace Shop.ViewModels
{
    public class CarsListViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<Car> allCars {  get; set; }
        public string currCategory { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and code AllCars

```
@model Car

<div class="col-lg-4">
    <img class="img-thumbnail" src="@Model.img" height="300" width="300" alt="@Model.Name" />
    <h2>@Model.Name</h2>
    <p>@Model.shortDesc</p>
    <p>Ціна: @Model.price.ToString("c")</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-warning" href="#">More details</a></p>
</div>
```

I read a similar article, where the guy was recommended to add the .cshtml extension or the full path, it didn’t help me
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xniad.png)

Comment: Do you have AllCars.cshtml file? And which folder is it situated?

Comment: yes, i have,the path /Views/Shared/AllCars.cshtml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are using net core , you can try the new syntax

```
 <partial name="AllCars" data="@car" />
```

and make shore that you have AllCars.cshtml in a proper folder